# jquerymobile and AJAX

Tags: jquery-mobile

seems to me that I didn't fully understand the concept behind jquerymobile, because I have no idea how to solve this issue.

What I want to do is load some HTML Content via AJAX, according to location.hash, put it into a new page and load this page.

But if I create a page myself by using the `pagebeforechange` event, jquerymobile just ignores it, creates its own div and my content won't be displayed.

### How do I have to do it?

Edit:
This is how I am currently doing it, but it wont't work.

```
$(function() {

    getPageContent(top.location.href, false);

    $(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {

            getPageContent(data.toPage, true);
    });


});



function getPageContent(pageUrl, changedPage) {

    var re = /.*\/#(.*)/;
    var result;


    result = re.exec(pageUrl);


    window.page = result[1].substr(0,3);
    window.id = result[1].substr(3);



    window.ajaxUrl = "request.php?page="+window.page+"&id="+window.id;

    $.ajax({

        url: window.ajaxUrl,

        success: function(data) {

            if(data.error) {
                alert(data.error);
            }
            else if(data.data) {
                if(changedPage) {
                    changePage(data.data));
                }
                else {
                    $('#content[role="main"]').html(atob(data.data));
                    setupPage();
                }

            }
            else {
                alert("UNKNOWN ERROR: "+data);
            }       
        }

    });

}

function changePage(html) {


    var div = "<div></div>";

    var newPage = $(div).attr("data-role", "page").attr("data-url", window.page+window.id);

    var header = $(div).attr("data-role", "header");
    var content = $(div).attr("data-role", "content");
    var footer = $(div).attr("data-role", "footer");

    $("body").append(newPage);
    newPage.append(header, content, footer);

    content.html(html);

    newPage.page();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete edit of the whole answer:

First. Set your body id to `id=body`. Then when you want to load the new page and change to it, use an ajax call like this:

```
$.get(window.ajaxUrl, function(data){
    $('#body').append("<div id='newPage' data-role='page'></div>"); //Creates a new page.
    $('#newPage').html(data); //Loads the html content into the new page.
    $.mobile.changePage('#newPage'); //Navigates to the new page.
}
```

This sends an ajax call with the method GET to the url found in your `window.ajaxUrl`. If the call is successful, it creates a new page named "newPage", and fills it with the data received from the ajax call. Then redirects to the newly created page.

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Naning/gaB6r/6/) shows the basics of how it works. However, it doesn't use any ajax call.

Comment: Okay, but that would mean that I'd have to create an onClick function for every button on my page, isn't there a way to use the click hijacking of jquery-mobile to this automatically?

Comment: I completely redid the answer. However, I didn't understand your question in the comment above. If you simply want to load an existing page you do that with $.mobile.changePage("url");

Comment: No, I want to have that behavior for ALL links on my page.
That is what I'm looking for.
I did it by catching the `pagebeforechange` event as you can see above, but it wouldn't work...

Comment: You can call the same function from each button's onclick, but with different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the page with jQueryMobile :

```
 $("#your-page").trigger("create");
```

--Edit

```
<script> 
     $("#thepage").live("pageshow", function(){
        $("#thepage).trigger("create");
       });
</script>
```

Change the content of  #thepage before 'pageshow' event

Comment: But when do I have to call it?
In the `pagebeforechange` event?

And do I create pages by simply adding `div`-elements to the `body`?

Could you maybe provide some more sample code?

Comment: You call it after you finished loading and handling the loaded html content.

Comment: But where should I load the HTML Content?

Comment: I'll post my own separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does this for you automatically - just make a regular link to the page and jquery mobile will shwo the loading spinner, load it in the background via ajax, then transition to the new page.

Make sure all your pages are decide with unique IDs and data-role='page'.  Check out the start guide here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/about/getting-started.html